# MPI and request/reply

Tags: mpi, openmpi, request-response

Does the MPI standard implement the request-reply communication pattern?

Reading about MPI I found that there are *point-to-point routines* like:

- Synchronous send
- Blocking send / blocking receive
- Non-blocking send /non-blocking receive
- Buffered send
- Combined send/receive
- "Ready" send

Maybe a developer can implement the request-reply communication pattern using these routines, but it seems that MPI does not directly implement it.

**Edit**: For clarifying purposes the request-reply (request-response) is a message exchange pattern in which a *requestor* sends a request message to a *replier* system which receives and processes the request, ultimately returning a message in response. This is a simple, but powerful messaging pattern which allows two applications to have a two-way conversation with one another over a channel. This pattern is especially common in client–server architectures. It may be synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: what do you mean by request/reply ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I will add info about it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available as-is.

That being said, this is trivial to implement.
The requestor can `MPI_Sendrecv()` and the replier can `MPI_Recv()` the request and then `MPI_Send()` the answer.